# Change names geom_bar plots with greek letters and subscript (for tornado plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would need to customize my variables names within my tornado plot to insert letters in subscript and greek letters.

My plot:

```
plot_sa<-ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = fig_sa_tot %>% 
             filter(sa_val =="total"), 
           aes(y=reorder(parameters, estimate), x=estimate, fill='total'), 
           stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(data = fig_sa_tot %>% 
             filter(sa_val =="first"), 
           aes(y=parameters, x=estimate, fill='first'),
           stat = "identity")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

My graph:

[image: graph]

I would like to change a_2 to a<sub>2</sub> for example and to display beta in real Greek letters...

I tried different solutions, such as

```
my_y_labels<-setNames(c("a_2",
                        "p_uplift",
                        "P_hysp",
                        "N_2",
                        "beta_2",
                        "mu_2",
                        "a_1",
                        "mu_1",
                        "beta_1",
                        "N_1",
                        "beta_vh",
                        "r_c",
                        "sigma",
                        "d_c",
                        "d_s",
                        "viro_1",
                        "r_s",
                        "viro_2"),
                      c(bquote(a['2']),
                        bquote(p[uplift]),
                        bquote(p[hysplit]),
                        bquote(N['2']),
                        expression(beta['2']),
                        expression(mu['2']), 
                        bquote(a['1']), 
                        expression(mu['1']),
                         expression(beta['1']),
                        bquote(N['1']),
                        expression(beta[vh]),
                        bquote(r[c]),
                        expression(sigma),
                        bquote(d[c]),
                        bquote(d[s]),
                        expression(omega['1']),
                         bquote(r[s]),
                        expression(omega['2'])
                        ))
```

And also tried with `scale_y_discrete`:

```
 plot_sa <- ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = fig_sa_tot %>% 
             filter(sa_val =="total"), 
           aes(y=reorder(parameters, estimate) , x=estimate, fill='total'),
           stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(data = fig_sa_tot %>% 
             filter(sa_val =="first"), 
           aes(y=parameters,x=estimate,fill='first'),
           stat = "identity")+  
  scale_y_discrete(c('a_2'=bquote(a['2']),
                        'p_uplift'=bquote(p[uplift]),
                        'P_hysp'=bquote(p[hysplit]),
                        'N_2'=bquote(N['2']),
                        'beta_2'=expression(beta['2']),
                        'mu_2'=expression(mu['2']),
                        'a_1'= bquote(a['1']),
                        'mu_1'=expression(mu['1']),
                        'beta_1'= expression(beta['1']),
                        'N_1'=bquote(N['1']),
                        'beta_vh'=expression(beta[vh]),
                        'r_c'= bquote(r[c]),
                        'sigma'=expression(sigma),
                        'd_c'=bquote(d[c]),
                        'd_s'=bquote(d[s]),
                        'viro_1'=expression(omega['1']),
                        'r_s'=bquote(r[s]),
                        'viro_2'= expression(omega['2'])
                     ))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the ggtext package might be of use to you.

Illustration using your y-axis values & some random stuff for data / plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggtext)

# sample dataset with y-axis values matching thosein the question
df <- data.frame(y = c("a_2", "p_uplift", "P_hysp", "N_2", "beta_2", "mu_2",
                       "a_1", "mu_1", "beta_1", "N_1", "beta_vh", "r_c", 
                       "sigma", "d_c", "d_s", "viro_1", "r_s", "viro_2")) %>%
  mutate(x = seq(1, n()))
  
df <- df %>%
  
  # converts subscripts to format recognized in rmarkdown
  # basically we want "a_2" to become "a~2~", but "sigma" to remain "sigma" since
  # the latter has no subscript to begin with
  mutate(y = gsub("_", "~", y) %>%
           paste0(., "~") %>%
           gsub("~~", "", .)) %>%
  
  # replace Greek letters with unicode equivalents
  mutate(y = y %>%
           gsub("beta", "\u03b2", .) %>%
           gsub("mu", "\u03bc", .) %>%
           gsub("sigma", "\u03c3", .)) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown()) # specify markdown format for axis labels
```

[image: result]

[Link](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/%7Eraymond/software/howtos/greekscape.xhtml) to unicode reference I used (it was one of the top results when I googled for Greek letters in unicode).